# How to repeat a specific value 'n' times based on other column's array length?

Tags: python, python-polars

I would like to repeat a None value 'n' times, but 'n' should be defined by other column's array length. I give some simple code example to better illustrate this:

```
import polars as pl

# Create dummy LazyFrame
lf = pl.LazyFrame(
    {
        "col1": [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1]],
        "col2": [["A", "B", "C"], ["C"], ["D", "E"]],
    }
)

# Print DataFrame
lf.collect()

shape: (3, 2)
┌───────────┬─────────────────┐
│ col1      ┆ col2            │
│ ---       ┆ ---             │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[str]       │
╞═══════════╪═════════════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ ["A", "B", "C"] │
│ [1, 2]    ┆ ["C"]           │
│ [1]       ┆ ["D", "E"]      │
└───────────┴─────────────────┘

# Define condition
condition = pl.col("col2").arr.lengths().eq(pl.col("col1").arr.lengths())

# Apply condition (does not work as I expected)
lf = lf.with_columns(
    pl.when(condition)
    .then(pl.col("col2"))
    .otherwise(
        pl.repeat(
            value=None,
            n=pl.col("col1").arr.lengths(),
        )
    )
    .alias("col3")
).collect()

# Output
print(lf)

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ col1      ┆ col2            ┆ col3            │
│ ---       ┆ ---             ┆ ---             │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[str]       ┆ list[str]       │
╞═══════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ ["A", "B", "C"] ┆ ["A", "B", "C"] │
│ [1, 2]    ┆ ["C"]           ┆ null            │
│ [1]       ┆ ["D", "E"]      ┆ null            │
└───────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

I would like to obtain this DataFrame by applying the condition:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ col1      ┆ col2            ┆ col3            │
│ ---       ┆ ---             ┆ ---             │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[str]       ┆ list[str]       │
╞═══════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ ["A", "B", "C"] ┆ ["A", "B", "C"] │
│ [1, 2]    ┆ ["C"]           ┆ [null, null]    │
│ [1]       ┆ ["D", "E"]      ┆ [null]          │
└───────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

Where `col3` has arrays with the same length as `col1` arrays for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.repeat_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.repeat_by.html#polars.Expr.repeat_by).

```
(df.with_columns(col3 = pl.lit(None).cast(pl.Utf8))
   .with_columns(
      pl.col("col3").repeat_by(pl.col("col1").arr.lengths()))
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ col1      ┆ col2            ┆ col3               │
│ ---       ┆ ---             ┆ ---                │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[str]       ┆ list[str]          │
╞═══════════╪═════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ ["A", "B", "C"] ┆ [null, null, null] │
│ [1, 2]    ┆ ["C"]           ┆ [null, null]       │
│ [1]       ┆ ["D", "E"]      ┆ [null]             │
└───────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

You can also remove the lists with `.explode`, add an empty column and `.groupby` them back together.

```
(lf.with_row_count()
   .explode("col1")
   .with_columns(col3 = pl.lit(None).cast(pl.Utf8))
   .groupby("row_nr")
   .agg(
      pl.col("col1"),
      pl.col("col2").last(),
      pl.col("col3"))
   .with_columns(
      pl.when(pl.col("col2").arr.lengths() == pl.col("col3").arr.lengths())
        .then(pl.col("col2"))
        .otherwise(pl.col("col3"))
        .alias("col3"))
).collect()
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌────────┬───────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ col1      ┆ col2            ┆ col3            │
│ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---             ┆ ---             │
│ u32    ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[str]       ┆ list[str]       │
╞════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ ["A", "B", "C"] ┆ ["A", "B", "C"] │
│ 1      ┆ [1, 2]    ┆ ["C"]           ┆ [null, null]    │
│ 2      ┆ [1]       ┆ ["D", "E"]      ┆ [null]          │
└────────┴───────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

Where the result of the `.groupby` is:

```
(df.with_row_count()
   .explode("col1")
   .with_columns(col3 = pl.lit(None).cast(pl.Utf8))
   .groupby("row_nr")
   .agg(
      pl.col("col1"),
      pl.col("col2").last(),
      pl.col("col3"))
)
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌────────┬───────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ col1      ┆ col2            ┆ col3               │
│ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---             ┆ ---                │
│ u32    ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[str]       ┆ list[str]          │
╞════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ ["A", "B", "C"] ┆ [null, null, null] │
│ 1      ┆ [1, 2]    ┆ ["C"]           ┆ [null, null]       │
│ 2      ┆ [1]       ┆ ["D", "E"]      ┆ [null]             │
└────────┴───────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Can you explain why a double use of `with_columns` is needed? Also why `pl.lit(None)` and `pl.lit([None])` differ.

Comment: @Wayoshi `pl.lit(None)` creates a `null` dtype which wouldn't work with `.repeat_by` - `pl.lit([None])` doesn't, but I suppose explicitly casting would be better, i'll change that. Try: `df.select(pl.lit("moo").repeat_by(pl.col("col1").arr.lengths()))` - the `pl.lit()` only has a height of `1` - the first `.with_columns` adds it as a column, meaning it will have a height of `3`. I didn't do this initially and was confused by the results.

Comment: Thanks. This feels like something docs could clarify better, I don't understand why `[None]` gets a non-null dtype (shouldn't it be a literal of list dtype?) but `None` does. The `lit` being a height of 1 makes sense now that you lay it out, the broadcasting step doesn't happen where I thought it did.

Comment: @Wayoshi Yeah, I thought `[None]` would give a list type. Allowing `[]` inside `pl.lit` is only new, so perhaps this is a bug.

Comment: @Wayoshi I just saw https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8030 mentions the dtype issue.